# How to correct the box plot style?

Tags: google-earth-engine

While running the code for the NDVI trend and charting it as a box plot, the boxes are chaotically connected with each other. I want to preserve the line connecting boxes, but want to make it linear, like in the picture below
[image]

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");

var uzbekistan = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME','Uzbekistan'));

var bostanliq =uzbekistan.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME','Bostanlik district'));
Map.addLayer(bostanliq, {}, "Bostanliq");


                                 ////////////LANDSAT 5 TM////////////
var dataset_5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('1992-01-01', '2001-01-01')
    .filterBounds(bostanliq)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',15))
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(bostanliq)});

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors_5(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

dataset_5 = dataset_5.map(applyScaleFactors_5);

var dataset_list5 = dataset_5.toList(dataset_5.size());

print ('Landsat 5 list',dataset_list5);

var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};

Map.setCenter(70.223, 41.714, 8);

Map.addLayer(dataset_5, visualization, 'Landsat 5 Bostanaliq');

//NDVI
function addNDVI_LT5 (image) {
  
  var ndvi =image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

//SAVI
function addSAVI_LT5 (image) {
  
  var savi =image.expression(
  '((NIR - RED)/(NIR+RED +0.5))*(1+0.5)',{
  'NIR':image.select('SR_B4'),
  'RED':image.select('SR_B3'),}).rename('SAVI'); 
  return image.addBands(savi);
}


dataset_5 = dataset_5.map(addNDVI_LT5);

dataset_5 = dataset_5.map(addSAVI_LT5);

//Map.addLayer(dataset_5.select('NDVI'),{},"NDVI for Bostanliq");
var chart1 =ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: dataset_5.select(['NDVI','SAVI']),
  region:bostanliq,
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale:90}).setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions({
    linewidth:4,
    title:'NDVI and SAVI Time Series for Bostanliq from 1992 to 2000',
    interpolateNulls: true,
    vAxis: {title: 'VI', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
    pointSize:2,
    curveType: 'function',
    colors: ['green','brown'],
    hAxis: {title:'Date', format: 'YYYY-MM',titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true} }
  });
print(chart1);

var dic = ee.Dictionary({});

var values = dataset_5.toList(dataset_5.size()).map(function(image) {
  
  var ndvi = ee.Image(image).select('NDVI');
  
  var allReducers = ee.Reducer.median()
    .combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.min(), sharedInputs: true} )
    .combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.max(), sharedInputs: true} )
    .combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([25]), sharedInputs: true} )
    .combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([50]), sharedInputs: true} )
    .combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([75]), sharedInputs: true} );
  
  var stats = ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: allReducers,
    geometry: bostanliq,
    scale: 30});
  
  var date = ee.Image(image).date();
  var dateString = date.format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  
  var values = stats.values();
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(values.get(0), 
                          ee.Feature(null).set({'date': dateString,
                                                'NDVI_max': values.get(0),
                                                'NDVI_median': values.get(1),
                                                'NDVI_min': values.get(2),
                                                'NDVI_p25': values.get(3),
                                                'NDVI_p50': values.get(4),
                                                'NDVI_p75': values.get(5)}), 0);
  
});

values = ee.FeatureCollection(values.removeAll([0]));

print("values", values);

// Format the results as a list of DataTable rows

// We need a list to map() over
var dateList = values.aggregate_array('date');

print(dateList);

// Helper function to format dates as per DataTable requirements
// Converts date strings

function formatDate(date) {
  var year = ee.Date(date).get('year').format();
  var month = ee.Date(date).get('month').subtract(1).format();
  var day = ee.Date(date).get('day').format();
  return ee.String('Date(')
    .cat(year)
    .cat(', ')
    .cat(month)
    .cat(', ')
    .cat(day)
    .cat(ee.String(')'));
}

var rowList = dateList.map(function(date) {
  var f = values.filter(ee.Filter.eq('date', date)).first();
  var x = formatDate(date);
  var median = f.get('NDVI_median');
  var min = f.get('NDVI_min');
  var max = f.get('NDVI_max');
  var p25 = f.get('NDVI_p25');
  var p50 = f.get('NDVI_p50');
  var p75 = f.get('NDVI_p75');
  var rowDict = {
    c: [{v: x}, {v: median}, {v: min}, {v: max},
        {v: p25}, {v: p50}, {v: p75}]
  };
  return rowDict;
});

print('Rows', rowList);

// We need to convert the server-side rowList object
// to client-side javascript object
// use evaluate()
rowList.evaluate(function(rowListClient) {
  var dataTable = {
    cols: [
      {id: 'x', type: 'date'},
      {id: 'median', type: 'number'},
      {id: 'min', type: 'number', role: 'interval'},
      {id: 'max', type: 'number', role: 'interval'},
      {id: 'firstQuartile', type: 'number', role: 'interval'},
      {id: 'median', type: 'number', role: 'interval'},
      {id: 'thirdQuartile', type:'number', role: 'interval'}
    ],
    rows: rowListClient
  };

  var options = {
    title:'NDVI Time-Series Box Plot',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'NDVI',
      gridlines: {
        color: '#d9d9d9'
      },
      minorGridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: '',
      format: 'YYYY-MM',
      viewWindow: {
        min: new Date(1992, 0),
        max: new Date(2000, 0)
      },
      gridlines: {
        color: '#d9d9d9'
      },
      minorGridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    },
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    lineWidth: 1,
    series: [{'color': '#D3362D'}],
    interpolateNulls: true,
    intervals: {
      barWidth: 2,
      boxWidth: 4,
      lineWidth: 1,
      style: 'boxes'
    },
    interval: {
      min: {
        style: 'bars',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        color: '#777777'
      },
      max: {
        style: 'bars',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        color: '#777777'
      }
    },
    chartArea: {left:100, right:100}
  };
    
  var chart = ui.Chart(dataTable, 'LineChart', options);
  print(chart);
});
```

[image]